# Selecting the row with latest date in one column

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, select

I need to select the ID2 with the latest date. We have a dB with rows containing different products with valid from/to dates. I'm trying to find when the product's valid to date is within a period, and if it prolonged the service.

The issue arises when a product has 2 dates in the same period (months) in the Valid To date. I then need to pick the date that is greatest within that period.

Perhaps important to note is that there might be more rows with greater dates for the same ID2, meaning I cannot use some kind of MAX (at least I think).

In dB

```
ID1:| ID2:| ValidFrom: |  ValidTo:  | NextPayment:
A1  | 123 | 2014-05-03 | 2015-01-02 | 2015-02-26
A2  | 123 | 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-27 | 2015-02-26
A3  | 456 | 2014-06-18 | 2015-01-02 | NULL
A4  | 456 | 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-23 | NULL
```

What I'd like:

```
ID1:| ID2:| ValidFrom: |  ValidTo:  | NextPayment:
A2  | 123 | 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-27 | 2015-02-26
A4  | 456 | 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-23 | NULL
```

*EDIT: I use Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Your table has three dates.  It is really impossible to know what your question is really about.

Comment: Forgot about the database, edited it now.

I need to capture the rows which have the largest ValidTo dates within their respective ID2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have a solution for you. It works on many DBMS:**

```
SELECT dB.* FROM dB
JOIN(
    SELECT ID2, MAX(ValidTo) 'MAX_ValidTo' FROM dB GROUP BY ID2) tb 
ON dB.ID2 = tb.ID2 AND dB.ValidTo = MAX_ValidTo
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use query as below:

```
Select top 1 with ties Id1, Id2, ValidFrom, ValidTo, Nextpayment 
from yourtable
    order by row_number() over(partition by ID2 order by ValidFrom desc)
```

other way:

```
Select Id1, Id2, ValidFrom, ValidTo, Nextpayment from (
   Select *,
        RowN = Row_number() over(partition by Id2 order by ValidFrom desc)
from yourtable ) a
Where a.RowN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([Id], [date]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2017-04-10' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([Id], [date]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2017-04-15' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([Id], [date]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2017-04-08' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([Id], [date]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2017-05-27' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([Id], [date]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2017-05-22' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test_table] ([Id], [date]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2017-05-24' AS Date))
GO
```

query :

```
select Id, max(date) as "greatest date"
from test_table
group by DATEPART(mm,date),Id
```

output :

[image: output]